# Monitor goes in power save mode after startup

Tags: display, dvi, safe-mode

My monitor goes in to `Power Save Mode` after Windows startup when plugged in to the DVI port. It works in safe mode, and also when I plug the computer in to the TV with HDMI the port.

I updated the drivers, and the monitor works on an other computer.
I also reset CMOS.

So my guess is a bad motherboard... Does anyone have an idea?

Here's the specs:

- Asus p8z68-v pro gen3
- Intel i7 2600k
- 120 GB OCZ Agility 3
- 16 GB RAM Blue Corsair DDR3
- H80 Corsair liquid cooling
- xfx PRO750W 80Plus bronze power supply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried going into the Control Panel and changing the power settings?

Also, you may want to try checking your video card to see whether it's loose/damaged.

[Here's where I got my ideas from.](http://www.pchelpforum.com/xf/threads/monitor-goes-into-power-saving-mode-on-boot-up.114689/)

Comment: thanks, imma check but the graphic card is on the motherboard.

Comment: finaly, the power settings are fine.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Something must be starting up along with Windows when it isn't booting into Safe Mode. Try checking out the items listed in `Start > Run > msconfig` and disable half of the startup items. If the problem persists, disable the other half instead. Otherwise, re-enable half of the programs you disabled before. until the problem re-appears. Keep dividing the number of startup programs in half, and eventually you'll find out which one is causing the problem. If msconfig doesn't reveal it, try [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thanks, there was something called monitor status in msconfig and when i tried to disable it and reboot there was another monitor status that was checked. So I restored the computer to a couple of weeks ago and now it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share my experience which is very similar to what is described but slightly different config. My set up:

- Asus p8z68-v lx
- Intel i7 2600k
- SSD
- 16 GB RAM
- 650W PSU
- ATI GPU card
- Dell 27-inch

After some fiddling, the issue disappeared when I replaced the graphics card.
Hope this helps.